# How do I restore MATE panel settings from old backup

Tags: panel, mate, restore

I was playing around with the MATE Tweak tool and suddenly a stupid option removed all my panel applets and replaced with a default layout - that thing doesn't even confirm the destructive action first!

However, I do have a backup of my home folder in the old PC... What should I copy over to get my panel back? I tried looking for `.mateconf`, `.config/mate` or `dconf/user` to no avail - both on my new and old computers the DConf Editor didn't show anything useful under org.mate.panel, only default stuff.

Comment: puzzling. If I click 'save panel layout' in MATE Tweak, it's saved in `/usr/share/mate-panel/layouts` but where, indeed, are temporary changes stored locally if I never click that button? +1 and I'm investigating :-S

Comment: I've added another answer and that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

If you have backup of your dconf database file, which is usually in `~/.config/dconf/user` you can restore settings from that database. But some work needs to be done.

Dconf reads database values from a profile file (See [wiki here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators)). And the path of that profile file is read from the `DCONF_PROFILE` environment variable.

1. So, first create a file named `user2` in your home directory with content like this

   ```
   user-db:user2
   ```
2. Put your old dconf database file in `~/.config/dconf/` directory with name `user2`. There should be a file with name `user` already.
3. Open a terminal and extract the settings from old database

   ```
   DCONF_PROFILE=~/user2 dconf dump /org/mate > ~/mate-old
   ```

   This will dump the values from old dconf database in key-value format in `~/mate-old` file.
4. Now load the settings back into the current database

   ```
   dconf load /org/mate/ < ~/mate-old
   ```

This will restore most of the settings of mate.

**Extra:** If you want you can restore the whole database using `/` in place of `/org/mate`. But I'm not recommending this.

Comment: Unfortunately StackExchange's bizarre anti-edit bias strikes again, so commenting here: the answer contains an error. `dconf dump` paths must end with slashes. In addition, the author requested to restore panel settings, and there is no need to restore the full `/org/mate/` tree to do that - the panel settings are under `/org/mate/panel/`.

Answer (score 1):

These preferences are stored in the `dconf` database, which is written to when making changes in the GUI, the `gsettings` CLI (where lots of panel settings can be found) or `dconf` CLI.

According to `/usr/share/doc/dconf-gsettings-backend/README`

> All preferences are stored in a single large binary file.

I have determined by experiment (changing settings and observing the modification time of the file) that this single large binary file in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 is most definitely

```
~/.config/dconf/user
```

which isn't human readable, of course

```
$ file ~/.config/dconf/user
: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

If you don't have this file in your backup, then you probably can't use the backup to restore your panel settings :(

Comment: It is in the backup, indeed. However, I would not trust simply copying the file over - dconf has probably changed some properties during my new Ubuntu installation, as well as any other application might have done the same during the mean time. Given that it's a solid blob, I won't be able to "copy over" only the panel settings...
Well, I did try to access the `dconf-editor` to find those settings and manually copy over, but didn't find them there :(