# how to restore Mate panel

Tags: 16.04, panel, settings, mate

I was tweaking the mate panel trying to solve some other problem, when I changed the panel settings, from GNOME2, to something else. all my panel apps disappeared. Suspicious of that happening, I clicked the save button, before hand, but now I don't know how to restore my panel apps, there is no button for that.

From Zanna's comment, it would appear I am missing a feature of Mate Tweak. I don't see the panel option anywhere. This might be why I cannot restore my save. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz6sh.jpg

Comment: Am I missing the point? When you click save, your panel settings get saved as a custom option you can restore [like this](http://i.imgur.com/ZqhLf7R.png)

Comment: @Zanna It would appear I am missing the panel component of  mate tweak.  http://imgur.com/a/3VyWr

Comment: Indeed! But the drop-down menu in my image is the one that says GNOME 2 in your image

Comment: I just selected some of the others, and my panel apps are gone again. 
is there a file that handles this? Im ok with doing it manualy, or writing a script. But this, this is annoying.

Comment: yeah I know :S The settings are in a single binary file [How do I restore MATE panel settings from old backup](//askubuntu.com/q/805144)

Comment: The panel component is *not* missing. The word "Panels" is top-center in your image. The drop-down is just below that, where it says "Select a panel layout to change the user interface." The button itself says "GNOME 2" because that is what is currently selected. Click that button to see other options, including `Custom: yourname-tweak`.  If the button is near the top of the screen, you may have to scroll the contents after clicking -- the `Custom` options is likely at the top of the list and may not be initially visible due to limited screen space.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprising and unnatural behavior of mate-tweak -- you want to "tweak" your settings, but instead **you lose all of your prior customizations**.

To avoid loss when using the `Interface` tab, it is critical that **the first action you take** is to click `Save Panel Layout`.

After that, if something outrageous happens, you should be able to restore by selecting the `Custom` option from the drop-down that is immediately above `Save Panel Layout`.

---

Underlying this behavior, it seems, is the *wildly incorrect* notion by mate-tweak that it is the only tool that will be used to configure your panels.

Comment: If it's too late to take my advice, and you are looking for an automated way to restore your configuration, here's that question: https://askubuntu.com/q/805144/11522

Comment: I would stay away from the `Interface` tab altogether -- it's will bring you nothing but heartache.

Comment: I save my MATE panel with `dconf dump / > dconf.dump.out` and restore with `dconf load / < dconf.dump.out`

Comment: As of Ubuntu MATE 18.04, there doesn't seem to be an `Interface` tab.  Maybe that is now `Panel`.  I don't know if it still has the behavioral quirk that I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and found an easier workaround:

1. install `dconf-editor`
2. launch `dconf-editor`
3. go into org > mate > panel > general
4. the values in bold are the ones changed by `mate-tweak`: select each one of them and then "Set to default" in the bottom right corner
5. restart for good measure and never touch `mate-tweak` ever again

Answer (score 0):

I found my panels MISSING after using this tool. Opening them by using superkey +T and typing Mate-tweak, re-opened the tool.
Then, there was only the options gnome 2 or OpenSuse (no "custom" or anything.. who knows where the one I saved went..)
closing that. No panels.
opened again.
SELECTED icon size for menu items. Panels magically re-appear. try save again. No panels. Re-open tweak.. select icon size for panel icons. Menus magically re-appear.
How frustrating. Now I remember why I don't normally use Mate. (XFCE4 guy here, where it's easy to save several panel configs, and the panels don't just go away..)