# How to back up unity state?

Tags: unity, backup, customization, settings

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and have done some customization to unity like changing wallpaper, icon sizes and so. How can I back it up and restore it in some other machine, to be precise which file(s) should I copy?

The things I want to backup:

- My current wallpaper
- Launcher icon sizes
- Number of workspaces I have
- Color of Launcher

Albeit I can summarize it to everything I've changed through **unity-tweak-tool**.

Comment: You could create a script to set those settings for you.

Comment: @M.Becerra, I'm not that pro and pretty sure unity saves its settings to a file (every Linux well written program do). So I just want find that file for further use.

Comment: @MaskedMan Ok, first of all, there is a lot of different things that you want to be "backed up".  This can be done fairly easily with a script, as Becerra said, and  I could write one when I have time, but you need to state clearly which things do you want. So please edit your question and include a complete list of things that you want to be backed-up and restored.

Answer (score 1):

dconf stores its configuration in the file ...

```
~/.config/dconf/user
```

So backup that one. tweak-tool is about changing dconf settings.

- location to the wallpaper is in there. Not the wallpaper itself
- amount of viewports is in there
- size of launcher icons is in there
- color of launcher too

---

gsettings is the tool to change dconf. Example using wallpaper location:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///dir/to/wallpaper.jpg"
```

The "org.gnome.desktop.background" part is the structure inside dconf and picture-uri the parameter and the part in between "s the value.

Setting colors for background:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#FFFFFF"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color "#FFFFFF"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type "solid"
```

- FFFFFF being black
- shading-ype: SOLID, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL are valid

---

Icon launcher size:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 32
```

- 32 being the size ;-)

This question [How to dump all the manully altered gsettings keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420527/how-to-dump-all-the-manully-altered-gsettings-keys) lists a method of dumping all settings changed by the user.

Comment: My wallpaper is a simple color however.

Comment: It would be nicer if you could show how to restore only that relevant parts from it

Comment: @MaskedMan was searching for the correct lines. background color and launcher icon size added.

Comment: I wrote this answer for a Mate question, it can be used for restore part. http://askubuntu.com/a/821571/61218

Whole directory under /compiz can be backed up